# How to change a IMG SRC using java in JSP?

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, src

I try change an image source by this code:

```
<img src="<% "http://www.image.com"; %>" alt="image" height="190" width="190" id = "picture">
```

But it won't display the image.

Comment: I think your code is incomplete.

Comment: `<%%>` will not evaluate, use `<%=%>`

Answer (score 1):

why don't you change the double quotes to single quote and try

```
<img src='<% "http://www.image.com"; %>' alt="image" height="190" width="190" id = "picture" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP scriptlet.

```
<img src="<%= url_var %>" alt="image" height="190" width="190" id="picture">
```

url_var is a java variable here, which puts the value into the src attribute.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: the question is incomplete,code is incomplete but still you are posting answer